# Conflict between polyglossia and ucharclasses

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, french, frenchspacing, ucharclasses

I have an issue with the following (Xe)LaTeX code where I want to get proper French spacing around the punctuation.

Here goes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
% \usepackage{ucharclasses}

\begin{document}
Ceci est un test: «avec des guillemets»
\end{document}
```

This yields a correct rendering:

[image: correct rendering]

However, if I uncomment the `ucharclasses` package, then the spacing gets incorrect:

[image: incorrect rendering]

I don't even need to load the `Latin` option of `ucharclasses` to get things wrong. I would love to not blame anyone and get things working, but have no idea where to start!

Comment: You are loading the latin option as the default is to setup all groups. If you use e.g. `\usepackage[Greek]{ucharclasses}` everything is fine.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike, I didn't know that point. As a matter of fact, in my complete document, I need to load the Latin block, otherwise the font doesn't switch back to my default font after I input characters from exotic blocks. That trick may be a workaround of a different issue I shall investigate though. However, why is that that loading Latin breaks the rules by polyglossia?

Comment: Both uses the same xetex feature (classes). It is certainly possible to reset things, but one would need to investigate first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ucharclass` package changes the class of the Latin characters, but `polyglossia` assumes this class is 0.

You can try with

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\makeatletter
\appto\french@punctuation{%
  \ifluatex\else
    \XeTeXinterchartoks \BasicLatinClass \french@punctthin = {\nobreak\thinspace}%
    \XeTeXinterchartoks \BasicLatinClass \french@punctthick = {\nobreakspace}%
    \XeTeXinterchartoks \french@punctguillstart \BasicLatinClass = {\nobreakspace}% "«a" -> "« a"
    \XeTeXinterchartoks \BasicLatinClass \french@punctguillend = {\nobreakspace}% "a»" -> "a »"
    \XeTeXinterchartoks \LatinSupplementClass \french@punctthin = {\nobreak\thinspace}%
    \XeTeXinterchartoks \LatinSupplementClass \french@punctthick = {\nobreakspace}%
    \XeTeXinterchartoks \french@punctguillstart \LatinSupplementClass = {\nobreakspace}% "«a" -> "« a"
    \XeTeXinterchartoks \LatinSupplementClass \french@punctguillend = {\nobreakspace}% "a»" -> "a »"
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Ceci est un test: «avec des guillemets»

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great to me <3 Just a last question @egreg : as I checked `gloss-french.ldf`, it seems you replaced/appended according to the `\z@` -> `\BasicLatinClass` pattern. But if I try to imagine the case `255 \french@punctthin`, how can I be sure it works well and the space is well replaced by a `\nobreak\thinspace`. No need to specify `\BasicLatinClass` anywhere? It seems to work fine on a toy example, but I don't get why it would work as is with `space` and not with `\z@`...

Comment: @xoolive I added also the Latin Supplement class. About class 255, there should be no problem, as class 0 is not involved. There are other problems, because the punctuation characters will not be recognized as Latin ones for transitions.

Comment: As a matter of fact, after I am done with a Unicode block, I must pay attention not to use a comma (the fonts I use don't have punctuation) but use a Latin character first in order to force the switching back to Latin. So there's a way to fix this? ... Btw, I must have been confused, but what does `class 255` stands for?

Comment: @xoolive From the reference guide (`texdoc xetex`): “The boundary of a text string is considered class 255, wherever there is a boundary between a ‘run’ of characters and something else — glue, kern, math, box, etc.”